# Session Variables are not being set/destroyed

Tags: php, session

On my live server, I have a **folder structure** like this:

```
- index.php
- unset.php
- info.php
- deep/
-- index.php
```

The code in the `index.php` which I'm using to see if the session variable is set or not, is as follows:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    print session_id();
    print "dev <br>";
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The code in the `deep/index.php` which I am using to set the session variable is as follows:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    print session_id();
    $_SESSION['usr'] = "bro";
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

And finally the `unset.php` file which unsets the session. The code in the file is:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo "<br>";
    echo session_id();
    echo "<br>";
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:/");
?>
```

### The Problem

If you go to http://test.haidrr.com
You will see the `/index.php` file which shows an empty array because the session variable is yet to be set. Note the `session_id()` on the top. Now if you go to `/deep`, The `index.php` file there will set a Session Variable which will show up in the array.
Alright now come back to `/` and if you're lucky, you will see the session varible in the array. (Which I don't see sometimes, Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't). Try to `/unset.php` the variable and the session variable is still there.

This example works perfectly on my localhost. I've also included a `info.php` file which has the `phpinfo()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can see the session set on following link.

http://test.haidrr.com/deep/

Could you please try with following to unset the session.

```
unset($_SESSION['usr']);
session_destroy();
```

Please let me know if you still find the problem

Comment: can you see the session set, back at the ``/``

Comment: Yes, I can see the session back on this also.
http://test.haidrr.com/

I updated the code, please check now

Comment: I can see session set on both the screens

http://test.haidrr.com/deep/
http://test.haidrr.com/index.php

And session is unset by unset.php also.

I think you're trying to access the session out the project directory.

Comment: What do you mean, "Out the project directory" ? I don't see anything working. Okay, the variable is being set, but not being unset!

Comment: how do I access the "index.php". I just go to test.haidrr.com
Isn't the server supposed to serve me the index.php by default?

Comment: Can you try with this 
unset($_SESSION); 
or
$_SESSION = array();

Comment: Yesterday I read on php docs that we should not use ``unset($_SESSION)`` because it also prevents the registering of global session varibles

Comment: That is correct.
but this should work at least unset($_SESSION['usr'])

Comment: and unset.php redirects you to ``/``. I can see the variable still there. Can't you?

Comment: hey, if i enable "disable cache" option in the chrome tools, this works perfectly!

Comment: And I think session is limited to that folder in which you set.

Comment: not correct. This works perfectly at [haider.base.pk/test](http://haider.base.pk/test)
This is a free service and here, the same code works perfectly.

Comment: sessions scope is based on the cookie.

by default a cookie is valid through the entire domain, ie domain.com and and subdirectories

if you want to limit that to a specific folder then you can specify it in the session cookie params.

Comment: you're missing the point. I don't want sessions to be limited to a folder. I want it to work!

Comment: same code that i've given above! and tbh, there is really not a point of unsetting all the variables manually. It's a different domain on which my given code works. And on this one, it doesn't. The hosting company even disabled cache on my domain. And I even got them to change my server.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue on server, but after see in cpanel memory was full.. I have remove some logs file and temporary files. session will works properly..

Please check memory of server and if it have not empty then please remove temporary files.

Comment: I've only used 14MB out of 1000MB, i don't think memory could be a problem